# How to change label content with timers throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, timer

I'm making an application and I'm using a timer in that application to change label content in WPF C# .NET.

In the timer's elapsed event I'm writing the following code

```
lblTimer.Content = "hello";
```

but its throwing an `InvalidOperationException` and gives a message *The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*

I'm using .NET framework 3.5 and WPF with C#.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What timer are you using? Specifically, what is the namespace of your timer?  .NET provides at least 3 AFAIK.

Comment: I'm using Timer Class from System.Timers namespace.

Comment: Sample code? SSCE plz (sscce.org)

Answer (score 11):

For .NET 4.0 it is much simpler to use a DispatcherTimer.  The eventhandler is then in the UI thread and it can set properties of the control directly.

```
private DispatcherTimer updateTimer;

private void initTimer
{
     updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle); 
     updateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnUpdateTimerTick);
     updateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
     updateTimer.Start();
}

private void OnUpdateTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTimer.Content = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

InvokeRequired doesn't work in wpf.

The proper way the update a GUI element owned by another thread is this :

Declare this on module level :

```
delegate void updateLabelCallback(string tekst);
```

This is the method to update your label :

```
private void UpdateLabel(string tekst)
    {
        if (label.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
        {
            updateLabelCallback uCallBack = new updateLabelCallback(UpdateLabel);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(uCallBack, tekst);
        }
        else
        { 
    //update your label here
        }
     }
```